# How to get template plain html without rendering with context vars in Jinja?

Tags: python, jinja2, tornado

I have pack of templates, that import and extend parent templates, I'd like to get templates rendered with those imports and extends but without rendering context vars for jinja.
Does jinja supports partial rendering with excluded or imported blocks?
Is it possible not to render context vars and get template?

Comment: Just don't pass any context variables to jinja.

Comment: @xyres, i mean to render template with variable names {{var}} but not rendering them at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Tornado, you can just read the templates and write them to the response. If you don't want to render them, don't use the `render` function.

Example:

```
class MyHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        with open('/path/to/template.html') as f:
            self.write(f.read())
```

---

**Another solution:**

Jinja2 [`Environment`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#jinja2.Environment) class allows you to customize the brackets used for context variables. That means, you can set these brackets - `{{ ... }}` to some other characters, like - `[[ ... ]]`, and Jinja2 will not render the old brackets. So, Jinja will not see these `{{ }}` as special characters and will output them just like any other character.

This is a simple example:

```
from jinja2 import Environment

env = Environment(
    ... other usual options ...
    variable_start_string='[[',
    variable_end_string=']]'
)
```

And then use this `env` to render your template. All the variables with curly brackets - `{{ ... }}` won't be rendered and yet the other extended templates will also be included.

Comment: it's a good point, but how to include\exclude\import other templates, if file has any?

Comment: @Oleksiy Well, including or extending other templates won't be possible this way. Another way I can think of is render the files using Jinja2 like you regularly do, and use the `raw` template tag to escape jinja syntax wherever you don't want to render the variables. See documentation: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#escaping

Comment: thx for that good point, I thought about this, but I have so many templates with excluding, so I decided raw mode would be awful monkey job

Comment: @Oleksiy I've updated the answer with another solution. Maybe it will solve your problem.